# How can i use a flag to draw or not to draw in the pictureBox paint event?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a flag in the Form1 top level: addFrame wich is set to false in the constructor.
Then in the picnt event i check if its false let me draw if its true also let me draw. The problem here is that i want to be able to draw when im running the program first time !
But when im moving the trackBar to the right i dont want it to draw anything .

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
        {


           Graphics g = e.Graphics;

           g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

               moveCounter++;
               label6.Text = moveCounter.ToString();



                   if (addFrame == false)
                   {
                       WireObjectGraphics.Draw(wireObject1, g);
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       addFrame = false;
                       WireObjectGraphics.Draw(wireObject1, g);
                   }

        }
```

This is the button click event where im clicking to set the addFrame to true:

```
private void button16_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        wireObjectAnimation1.AddFrame();
        addFrame = true;
        trackBar1.Select();
    }
```

And the scroll bar event in this case i want to make that if i move the trackBar to the right and there are no any draws already then just show the image in the pictureBox dont draw anything ! But if i move it to the right and there are already draws then do show them.

If i move it to the left allways show the previous draws.

```
private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (addFrame == false)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                currentFrameIndex = trackBar1.Value - 1;
                textBox1.Text = "Frame Number : " + trackBar1.Value;

                wireObject1.woc.Set(wireObjectAnimation1.GetFrame(currentFrameIndex));
                trackBar1.Minimum = 0;
                trackBar1.Maximum = fi.Length - 1; 
                if (checkBox1.Checked)
                {
                    setpicture(trackBar1.Value);
                    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image);
                    g.Clear(SystemColors.Control);
                    pictureBox1.Invalidate();
                }
                else
                {
                    setpicture(trackBar1.Value);
                }
                pictureBox1.Refresh();

                button1.Enabled = false;
                button2.Enabled = false;
                button3.Enabled = false;
                button4.Enabled = false;
                button8.Enabled = false;
                SaveFormPicutreBoxToBitMapIncludingDrawings(currentFrameIndex);

                return;

            }

        }
```

This is the draw function in the WireObjectGraphics class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;

namespace AnimationEditor
{
    class WireObjectGraphics
    {
        static Point connectionPointStart;
        static Point connectionPointEnd;
        static SolidBrush brush;
        static Pen p = null;

        public WireObjectGraphics()
        {

        }

        public static void Draw(WireObject wo, Graphics graphics)
        {
            brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
            p = new Pen(brush);
            Graphics g = graphics;
            WireObject wireObject1 = wo;

            if (wireObject1 != null)
            {
                for (int idx = 0; idx < wireObject1.woc.Point_X.Count; ++idx)
                {
                    Point dPoint = new Point((int)wireObject1.woc.Point_X[idx], (int)wireObject1.woc.Point_Y[idx]);
                    dPoint.X = dPoint.X - 5; // was - 2
                    dPoint.Y = dPoint.Y - 5; // was - 2
                    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(dPoint, new Size(10, 10));
                    g.FillEllipse(brush, rect);
                    // bitmapGraphics.FillEllipse(brush, rect);

                    // g.FillEllipse(brush, rect);
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < wireObject1._connectionstart.Count; i++)
                {

                    int startIndex = wireObject1._connectionstart[i];
                    int endIndex = wireObject1._connectionend[i];



                    connectionPointStart = new Point((int)wireObject1.woc.Point_X[startIndex], (int)wireObject1.woc.Point_Y[startIndex]);
                    connectionPointEnd = new Point((int)wireObject1.woc.Point_X[endIndex], (int)wireObject1.woc.Point_Y[endIndex]);
                    p.Width = 2;
                    g.DrawLine(p, connectionPointStart, connectionPointEnd);
                    // bitmapGraphics.DrawLine(p, connectionPointStart, connectionPointEnd);
                }
            }
        }

    }


}
```

What i need is that first time running the program to be able to draw !
Then when moving the trackBar to the righ to check if draws already exists show them if not exist show only the image and only when i click the button it will add the draws on the frame im on.

If i move to the left allways show the draws i did in the other frames.

WireObject class:

Constructor:

```
class WireObject
    {
        private string an;
        private bool fnExt;
        public string lockObject;
        private int idx;
        public WireObjectCoordinates woc;
        private List<int> connectionStart = new List<int>();
        private List<int> connectionEnd = new List<int>();

        private const string version = "01.00";

        string wo_name;


        public WireObject( string name )
        {
            wo_name = name;
            woc = new WireObjectCoordinates();
            fnExt = false;
        }
```

In the wireobject class i have some function like connecting points(pixels) like delete pixels like save and load...

WireObjectCoordinates class is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace AnimationEditor
{
    class WireObjectCoordinates
    {
        public List<float> Point_X = new List<float>();
        public List<float> Point_Y = new List<float>();

        public WireObjectCoordinates()
        {
        }

        public WireObjectCoordinates(WireObjectCoordinates w)
        {
            Point_X.AddRange(w.Point_X);
            Point_Y.AddRange(w.Point_Y);
        }

        public void Set(WireObjectCoordinates w)
        {
            if (w == null)
            {
            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Point_X.Count; i++)
                {
                    Point_X[i] = w.Point_X[i];
                    Point_Y[i] = w.Point_Y[i];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is still in Form1 with the flag when to show the pixels i mean when and how to call the paint event like pictureBox1.Refresh(); but oncei t will use the Draw function inside and once it will not. When i run the program let me use the draw function once i moved the trackBar to the right dont use the draw function.

Comment: My problem now is with the flag in addFrame in the scroll event and the paint event how to make that when the program is running let me draw and when im moving the trackBar to the right for example dont let me draw. Draw i mean show the draws i already did ! Show/Do not show.

Comment: Don't add info in a comment. Edit your question.

Comment: You are making us guess at what a WireObject is.

Comment: Can't you just find a way to simplify your question? What do you think is the error? Where precisely do you think something go wrong? Have you tried setting breakpoints (F9) & debugging step by step using F11 ?

Comment: LarsTech WireObject is a class i will add it now to the question.

Answer (score 0):

For a windows form control OnPaint is only called when a.) a window overlapping the current control is moved out of the way OR b.) you manually invalidate the control : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1e430ef4.aspx

So OnPaint should be getting called too often.